# window.open not working with IE9

Tags: php, javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I'm having trouble getting this to work in IE9:

*edit:* Sorry, I forgot to mention that $variable was a $_GET from a drop down menu selection.

I am currently offline,

```
<a href="#"
    onclick="window.open('https://domain.com/contact-form?chatq=<?php echo $variable;?>@domain.com','resizable=1,width=320,height=200'); return false;">
    <br />click to send an email.
</a>
```

It works fine in firefox and chrome. I'm not exactly sure what the problem is with IE.  Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Is that `<?php echo $variable;?>` in the actual output page?

Comment: Does the console have anything to say?

Comment: Is there an "invalid argument" error in the console?

Comment: have you tried with some simple param value for `chatq` or with no param at all

Comment: @leftclickben: yes it is, $variable is a $_GET from a dropdown selection and it'll open up to that person's contact form.

Comment: Why are you trying to use JavaScript for this rather than just setting the HREF of the tag to the target URL and using a Target parameter to open in a new window? Doing so is a better UX for the user and more reliable too.

Comment: @EricLaw Using the `target` attribute prevents the user from being able to disable the new window behaviour, which is actually a _bad_ UX not a good one.  There is nothing at all wrong with using `window.open`.  If the user doesn't want a new window they can disable javascript.

Comment: @user2634512 If you are seeing that `<?php...?>` literally in the page source from the browser, then something has gone wrong.  That is supposed to be processed by PHP and output as the value of `$variable`, not see some PHP code in the browser source.

Answer (score 1):

Tested on IE9:

```
<?php

$variable = 3;

?>

<a 
onclick="window.open('https://domain.com/contact-form?chatq=<?php echo $variable;?   >@domain.com','resizable=1,width=320,height=200'); return false;">
<br />click to send an email.

</a>
```